# Prove that the even (odd) degree Legendre polynomials are even > (odd) functions of $t$.

Tags: legendre-polynomials

> **a.)** Prove that the even (odd) degree Legendre polynomials are even
>   (odd) functions of $t$.
>
> **b.)** Prove that if $p(t) = p(-t)$ is an even polynomial, then all the
>   odd order coefficents $c_{2j+1} = 0$ in its Legendre expansion $p(t) =
>  c_0q_0(t) + ... + c_nq_n(t)$ vanish.

Is "a" similar to proving that Legendre polynomials of even and odd degree are orthogonal and for "b" I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) 
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left[(x^2-1)^n \right].
$$
Here $(x^2-1)^n$ is an even polynomial. Taking the $n$-th derivative the general terms have the form $a_k x^{2k-n}$ which is even iff $n$ is even, and odd iff $n$ is odd.

b) Writing out the Legendre-Fourier coefficients by integral on $[-1,1]$, then the integrand $p(t)P_{2n+1}(t)$ is an *odd* function so the value of the integral is $0$. (The situation is similar to the classical trigonometric Fourier series case on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Vesszabo, sry to bother you on this question again but can you further elaborate on b.? I understood a but I did not understand b ?